# In C program which remove duplicates from an array, when I print an array, the output is not true

Tags: c, arrays

This program which written in C should remove duplicated elements from 2 input arrays by user, so when I print the second array which is `b[z]` after removing duplicates, the output is not true as it prints weird number instead of the input number by the user. **(the problem in code is determined by comment)**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int n, z ;
    printf("Enter size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    if(n <= 20) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
            printf("Enter integer \n");
            scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter size of the 2nd array\n");
    scanf("%d", &z);
    int b[z];
    if(z <= 20) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < z; i++) {
            printf("Enter integer \n");
            scanf("%d", &b[z]);
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < z; i++) {
        printf("%d ", b[z]);
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(a[i] == a[j]) {
                for(int l = j; l < n; l++)
                {
                    a[l] = a[l + 1];
                }
                n--;
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nArray1: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < z; t++) {
        for(int u = t + 1; u < z; u++) {
            if(b[t] == b[u]) {
                for(int l = u; l < z; l++)
                {
                    b[l] = b[l + 1];
                }
                z--;
                u--;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\nArray2: ");
    for(int e = 0; e < z; e++) {
        printf("%d ", b[e]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your innermost loops, `l + 1` may be `n` or `z`, which is one beyond te valid range of the arrays. By the way, what happens, if the input `n` or `z` are greater than 20?

Comment: what you mean by In your innermost loops, l + 1 may be n or z, which is one beyond te valid range of the arrays                                                                                 the <20 is the biggest size of array

Comment: I mean that your loop condition enforces that `l < n`, so that `l` can be at most `n - 1`. When that is the case, `l + 1` is `n` and `a[l + 1]` accesses invalid memory.

Comment: it works in first loop which eliminate duplicates for array a[n] , but do not work for array b[z]

Comment: There's also an error when you read the input: `scanf("%d", &b[z])` should be `scanf("%d", &b[i])`. The same error happens when you print the second array. Instead of repeating the same code for the two arrays with different indices, consider writing functions for these tasks. That way you have to fix the errors only in one place.